# Getting a 404 error with flask and views

Tags: python, flask

I'm still new with Flask and I am trying to put together a very simple site. Here is my code.

(app.py)

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import os
from flask import (Flask, session, redirect, url_for, abort,
               render_template, flash, request)
from werkzeug import secure_filename


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/image')
def image():
    return render_template('image.html')

@app.route('/video')
def video():
    return render_template('video.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In my layout.html I have links which lead to the html files above but yet when I run my app.py and click on a link, it takes me to a 404 page and I'm really unsure of why.

Here is the layout.html

```
<ol class="naviA">
    <li class="navi">
        <a class="navi" href="/image.html"><p>Image</p></a></li>
        <li class="navi"><a class="navi" href="/music.html"><p>Music</p></a></li>
        <li class="navi"><a class="navi" href="/video.html"><p>Video</p></a></li>
        <li class="navi"><a class="navi" href="/link.html"><p>Links</p></a></li>
        <li class="navi"><a class="navi" href="/storage.html"><p>Storage</p></a></li>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Do all of the templates exist and if they do, where? Please also show the `layout.html` in which the links exist. Can you hit these endpoints successfully via browser or curl?

Comment: Hi, I have edited with the links in the layout.html and the layout.html loads successfully and is in the same templates folder as the rest of them but only the layout.html loads.

Comment: @RetroCoNoR Provide us with complete information to run your app - we miss your termplates. It is likely, you generate urls which are not served by our Flask app. You shall see the attempts to see some page on your console, where you have started the Flask app - could you provide that? It is likely to answer your problem. Or it is not there at all, then you are trying to visit completely different web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are linking to the endpoints incorrectly. Remove the `.html` in the links and you should be fine.

```
<ol class="naviA">
    <li class="navi">
        <li class="navi"><a class="navi" href="/image"><p>Image</p></a></li>
        <li class="navi"><a class="navi" href="/music"><p>Music</p></a></li>
        <li class="navi"><a class="navi" href="/video"><p>Video</p></a></li>
        <li class="navi"><a class="navi" href="/link"><p>Links</p></a></li>
        <li class="navi"><a class="navi" href="/storage"><p>Storage</p></a></li>
    </li>
</ol>
```

If you look at your `@app.route`-decorators, they define the endpoint as so:

```
@app.route('/image')
def image():
    return render_template('image.html')
```

This means that you now have a URL which ends at `/image`. The template surely ends with `.html` but your flask app does not serve such an endpoint, it loads that template and fills it with data your functions provide.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @msvalkon said, you should use `url_for()` to generate URLs in templates, as it is cleaner, more secure and simply "the way" to do it. Here are some [examples](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/templates/) on it.

Hence, one of your links in the template might look like:

```
<li class="navi"><a class="navi" href="{{ url_for('image') }}"><p>Image</p></a></li>
```